# Patching render_to_response using Mock

Tags: python, django, mocking

I am using [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html) and I am not able to patch django's render_to_response function properly. For e.g., the following test never fails:

```
    from django.test.client import Client
    from mock import patch
    import nose.tools as nt

    @patch('django.shortcuts.render_to_response')
    def test_should_fail(self, render_to_response):
        def assert_response(url, context, context_instance):
            nt.assert_false(True)
        render_to_response.side_effect = assert_response
        response = Client().get('/some/url/')
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:** The reason I want to do this is that in my view, I am rendering the response like:

```
form = SomeFormClass(label_suffix='')
return render_to_response('admin/send_info_message.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In my test, I want to test that these parameters are correctly called, like:

```
 def assert_response(url, context, context_instance):
     nt.assert_equal('admin/survey_question.html', url)
     nt.assert_equal({'form': SomeForm()}, context)
     nt.assert_equal(RequestContext(response.request), context_instance)

 render_to_response.side_effect = assert_response
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, why do you want to do this?

Secondly, the place you should patch a function is the place you are calling it - ie in the views module that handles the relevant URL. For example:

```
@patch('myapp.views.render_to_response')
```

Comment: In my view, rendering the response like: 

`return render_to_response('content.html', {'form': form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))`

I want to test this is called with correct arguments.

Comment: Well, that's not really what unit tests are for. But regardless, my example shows you what to do.

Comment: Daniel, isn't this exactly the kind of thing the python mock package was designed to solve?

Comment: Oh, my mistake! You don't actually need to patch the render_to_response() method because client.get() returns a "response" object with the template context. Just look at response.context. There's no need to patch at all.